# Symfony5 create a user for testing

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I have a `PurchaceFactory` and one of its parameter is a `User` entity object.

I would like to create a user:

```
class PurchaceFactoryTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCreate()
    {
        $user = new User();

        $user->setEmail('user1@email.com');
        $user->setPassword('password');
        $user->setRoles(["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_BUY"]);

        $jsonEncoder = new JsonEncoder();

        $artworkData = [
            "ID"        => 129884,
            "title"     => "Starry Night and the Astronauts",
            "author"    => "Alma Thomas",
            "thumbnail" => [
                "lqip"     => "data:image/gif;base64,somebase64data",
                "width"    => 800,
                "height"   => 600,
                "alt_text" => "Al text"
            ]
        ];

        $purchaceFactory = new PurchaceFactory($jsonEncoder);
        $purchace = $purchaceFactory->create($user, $artworkData);
        //assertions
        //...
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I can not set the `id` of the user, since there is no `setId` for the entity when I made the `bin/console make:user`.

The `purchaseFactory` use that property of `$user`.

How could I simulate a `User` object with `id`?

I do not want to modify the `UserEntity` and add `setId` because id should be immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a TestUser entity and extending it with the User entity. Then deactivate the strategy for setting the id in the property id.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class TestUser extend User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}

$user = new TestUser();
$user->setId(1000);
```

Comment: I could not see the forest from the tree. I've read about this on symfonycast, I just do not use tests usually. Anyway, it works well, thank you.