# Symfony / PHPUnit : how to test function using identifier?

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony6

Is there a way, when using PHPUnit with Symfony, to assert a function using the entity identifier in it ?

I am trying to use PHPUnit for my project, but even after many tries and researches, I still haven't find how to assert a function when there is an autogenerated identifier. Like, for the code below :

```php
// tests/Entity/UserPlaylistTest.php

namespace App\Tests\Entity;

use App\Entity\UserPlaylist;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class UserPlaylistTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function getEntity() : UserPlaylist
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->setId( 'user' );
        $user->setName( 'User' );

        $playlist = new Playlist;
        $playlist->setId( 'playlist' );
        $playlist->setName( 'Playlist' );

        $userPlaylist = new UserPlaylist;
        $userPlaylist->setUser( $user );
        $userPlaylist->setPlaylist( $playlist );

        return $userPlaylist;
    }

    public function testName() : void
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $userPlaylist = $this->getEntity();
        $this->assertEquals( $userPlaylist->getName(), 'User: Playlist' );
    }
}
```

How can I assert `UserPlaylist::getKey()` ?

```php
// src/Trait/ItemTrait.php

namespace App\Trait;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait ItemTrait
{
    #[
        ORM\Id,
        ORM\Column( length: 30 ),
    ]
    private string $id;

    #[ ORM\Column( length: 100 ) ]
    private string $name;

    public function setId( string $id ) : self
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getId() : string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName( string $name ) : self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName() : string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

```php
// src/Entity/User.php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ ORM\Entity( repositoryClass: UserRepository::class ) ]
class User implements UserInterface
{
    use ItemTrait;
}
```

```php
// src/Entity/Playlist.php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PlaylistRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PlaylistRepository::class)]
class Playlist
{
    use ItemTrait;
}
```

```php
//src/Entity/UserPlaylist.php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserPlaylistRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ ORM\Entity( repositoryClass: UserPlaylistRepository::class ) ]
class UserPlaylist
{
    #[
        ORM\Id,
        ORM\Column,
        ORM\GeneratedValue(),
    ]
    private int $id;

    #[
        ORM\ManyToOne( inversedBy: 'userPlaylists' ),
        ORM\JoinColumn( nullable: false ),
    ]
    private ?User $user = null;

    #[
        ORM\ManyToOne( inversedBy: 'userPlaylists' ),
        ORM\JoinColumn( nullable: false ),
    ]
    private ?Playlist $playlist = null;

    public function getId() : int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setUser( ?User $user = null ) : self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser() : ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setPlaylist( ?Playlist $playlist = null ) : self
    {
        $this->playlist = $playlist;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlaylist() : ?Playlist
    {
        return $this->playlist;
    }

    public function getKey() : string
    {
        $userId = $this->getUser()?->getId() ?? '';
        $playlistId = $this->getPlaylist()?->getId() ?? '';
        return $this->getId() . '#' . $userId . '#' . $playlistId;
    }

    public function getName() : string
    {
        $key = $this->getId();

        static $cache;
        if ( isset( $cache[ $key ] ) )
            return $cache[ $key ];

        $userName = $this->getUser()?->getName() ?? '';
        $playlistName = $this->getPlaylist()?->getName() ?? '';

        return $cache[ $key ] = $userName . ': ' . $playlistName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything that the autogeneration of the number makes you believe you need to test it? It should normally suffice that if you get a number it works, the concrete number itself is just a detail you normally don't need to test at all. For everything else use mocks. And the test-code is missing from the question, it is often most important, even if you have it incomplete right now, that then makes your question much more clear and should give better feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you asked, I added the test-code. The problem for me is that I cache the return of a function, the UserPlaylist identifier being used in it, as you can see. Is there anything I could do, or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @Xem Do you want to set the id for the test?

Comment: @Bademeister I think that's what I need to do, as the console tell me `Error: Typed property App\Entity\UserPlaylist::$id must not be accessed before initialization` when I launch the PHPUnit tests. But I'm not an expert in testing, maybe there's a better way to test it, I don't know.

Comment: @Xem There is little point in setting the ID and relying on the result of getId. You can use that ID for your test. If you really want to set the ID for your test, you can do it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582938/symfony5-create-a-user-for-testing/76584740#76584740